# Adjust spacing in the title page using the scrbook package

Tags: spacing, titles

The title of my document has three lines. In the title page, the width of the first and the third lines are almost equal as in the following example.

[image]

I want to slightly expand the spacing between the letters in the third line, such that the width of first and the third line coincide.

How can I accomplish that?

The code which produced the example is the following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,BCOR=15mm,DIV=11,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\titlehead{
\begin{minipage}[b]{120mm}
\sc
University XYZ\\
blablu\\
lule\\
group q\\    
\end{minipage}
}
\title{This is the very first line\\and here\\comes the second line}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{asfl asfoksf}
\date{\formatdate{31}{03}{1685}}
\publishers{
\large
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
  azjli: & & aspgadg
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: ,@Lisa [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I strongly discourage you to do this, it is not at all good typography  practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to, then here is a solution with the help of the `calc` package. First, you calculate the width of the first line by:

```
\newcommand{\Space}{\widthof{\huge\sffamily\bfseries This is the very first line}}
```

then, this `\Space` is used as the width dimension for a `minipage`. We insert the third line of the title into this `minipage` with the `linebreak` ending. The `linebreak` command will make the phrase occupy the total width which is the same as the first phrase.

Here is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,BCOR=15mm,DIV=11,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\Space}{\widthof{\huge\sffamily\bfseries This is the very first line}}

\titlehead{
\begin{minipage}[b]{120mm}
\sc
University XYZ\\
blablu\\
lule\\
group q\\ 
\end{minipage}
}
\title{%
This is the very first line\\and here\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\Space} comes the second line \linebreak \end{minipage}
}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{asfl asfoksf}
\date{\formatdate{31}{03}{1685}}
\publishers{
\large
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
  azjli: & & aspgadg
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

[image]